# SQLite-connect() blocks due to unrelated connect() on separate process

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, multiprocessing

I want to launch a separate process that connects to a SQLite-db (the ultimate goal is to run a service on that process). This typically works fine. When I however connect to another db-file before launching the process, the `connect()` command is completely blocking: neither does it finish, nor does it raise an Error.

```
import sqlite3, multiprocessing, time

def connect(filename):
    print 'Creating a file on current process!'
    sqlite3.connect(filename).close()

def connect_process(filename):
    def process_f():
        print 'Gets here...'
        conn = sqlite3.connect(filename)
        print '...but not here when local process has previously connected to any unrelated sqlite-file!!'
        conn.close()

    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_f)
    process.start()
    process.join()

if(__name__=='__main__'):
    connect_process('my_db_1') # Just to show that it generally works
    time.sleep(0.5)

    connect('any_file') # Connect to unrelated file

    connect_process('my_db_2') # Does not get to the end!!
    time.sleep(2)
```

This returns:

```
> Gets here...
...but not here when local process has connected to any unrelated sqlite-file!!
Creating a file on current process!
Gets here..
```

So we would expect another line to be printed at the end `...but not here when...`

Remarks:

- I know that SQLite cannot candle concurrent access. It should however
  work here for 2 reasons: 1) the file I connect to on my local process
  is different to the separately created one. 2) the connection
  on the former file is long closed by the time the process gets
  created.
- The only operation I use here is to connect to the DB and
  then close the connection immediately (which creates the file if not
  existing). I have of course verified that we get the same behavior if we
  actually do anything meaningful...
- The code is just a minimal working example for what I really want to do. The goal is to test a service
  that uses SQLite. Hence in the test-setup, I need to create some mock
  SQLite-files… The service is then launched on a separate process in order to test it via the respective client.

Comment: I tried your script above and it works, [here](https://gist.github.com/philippkeller/8cfed51e6f197452d846467a9b71c15f) is my output

Comment: Thanks @hansaplast, I seems that on Linux it works.
On osX not however...

Comment: I ran this on OSX, can you provide your setup? (e.g. exact python version, how you execute the script etc.)

Comment: btw: I ran your script with no sqlite db prepared, so I guess it created the sqlite3 dbs on the fly, this might be different to your setup

Comment: I use python 2.7 in a virtual-environement. Do you use 3?
I run the scrip via `python <script_name>` in the console.

Comment: I tried on python27 as well. Can you try to delete all the sqlite files and run the script again?